# How to improve sql query performance?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

```
SELECT Round(( Cast(sysdate AS DATE) - Cast(actual_end_time AS DATE) ) * 24 * 60 
       ) AS diff_minutes 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  task_name = "running" 
ORDER  BY actual_end_time DESC
```

We have an index on column `task_name`

Is there any other options to improve this query?

Comment: Do you have problem with this query? How is the performance now? Show us the `analyze` plan

Comment: Do you have an index on `actual_end_time`? Ordering a result set is a very costly operation. Also, how many rows does the result set have? (*If you don't have an index on `actual_end_time` then that is the source of the problem*)

Comment: How many rows are there in the table?  How many rows have a `task_name` of "running"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your query, you want a composite index on `table1(task_name, actual_end_time)` (note the order of the columns in the index is important).  This is a covering index for the query and satisfies the `where` and `order by` clauses.